# Missing libQt5PrintSupport_debug.a

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qmake, vcpkg

I'm building a Qt5 (installed through vcpkg) project on macOS.

It builds nicely on QtCreator, debug mode. But when I try to build it from command line, also debug mode, then I get

```
make: *** No rule to make target `/Users/user/vcpkg/installed/x64-osx/lib/libQt5PrintSupport_debug.a', needed by `project.app/Contents/MacOS/project'.  Stop.
```

I see `libQt5PrintSupport_debug.a` installed at
`vcpkg/installed/x64-osx/debug/lib/libQt5PrintSupport_debug.a`

So might be that when things are done from command line   `vcpkg/installed/x64-osx/debug/lib/`  is not being searched, I guess.

How can I add this to the searched path list?

Is there a specific environment variable on macOS where `.a` are searched?

Building in release mode from command line works fine.

Comment: Do you know which `qmake` ist used? If it is the one from vcpkg that is only setup for release. If you are able to control what executable is called then you can provide a script which calls `qmake` with option `--qtconf qt.debug.conf` to use the debug paths.

Comment: Yes, I was using qmake from `vcpkg/installed/x64-osx/tools/qt5/bin`. Using the one from `vcpkg/installed/x64-osx/tools/qt5/debug/bin`instead seems to solve the problem.